# how to align the decimal values in a ksh script report

Tags: shell, awk, sh

am trying to align the value inside awk.. but still am facing some alignment issue.. could you please help.

am getting below format.,

```
                Code 0011               0.00
                Code 0012               0.00
                Code   17               1,234.23
                Code   37               123,456.12
                Code   41               2,345.12
           Total Amount                 8.41
          0011 Record Count              0
         0012 Record Count              0
           17 Record Count              2
           37 Record Count              1
           41 Record Count              2
        Total Record Count              1
```

but am expecting like below.,all decimal needs to align properly..

```
                Code 0011                    0.00
                Code 0012                    0.00
                Code   17                1,234.23
                Code   37              123,456.12
                Code   41                2,345.12
           Total Amount                      8.41
          0011 Record Count             0
         0012 Record Count              0
           17 Record Count              2
           37 Record Count              1
           41 Record Count              2
        Total Record Count              1
```

also the record count need to match with previous line.,

```
            Code   37                    123,456.12
            Code   41                      2,345.12
           Total Amount                        0.00
         0319 Record Count                        0
         0329 Record Count                       11                    
         0339 Record Count                      321
```

here is the code which i tried.,

```
awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile" -v ts="$ts"  -v tc="$tc" -v sq="'" '
     {
            printf("%14s Code %s%15s%" sq ".2f\n"," ",$1," ",$2) >> outfile
            r[NR] = $1
            c[NR] = $3
    }
      END {printf("%14s Total Amount                 %" sq ".2f\n "," ",ts) >> outfile
              for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) printf("%12s %s Record Count %11s  %s\n"," ",r[i]," ",c[i]) >> outfile
     }' FS=, OFS=, trancodestotalsumt.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to know a maximum length the numbers i `trancodestotalsumt.txt` can have or process the file twice to calculate it in the first pass. Assuming that you know the maximum width, replace

```
printf("%14s Code %s%15s%" sq ".2f\n"," ",$1," ",$2) >> outfile
```

with

```
#                              vv--- here
printf("%14s Code %s%15s%" sq "10.2f\n"," ",$1," ",$2) >> outfile
```

to extend the width of the token to n characters (10 in this case).

To remember the length in a first pass, bearing in mind that I have no test data, use

```
awk -F, -v outfile="$outfile" -v ts="$ts"  -v tc="$tc" -v sq="'" '
     NR == FNR {
       width = length(sprintf("%" sq ".2f", $2));
       if(width > maxwidth) maxwidth = width;
       next
     }
     {
        printf("%14s Code %s%15s%" sq maxwidth ".2f\n"," ",$1," ",$2) >> outfile
        r[NR] = $1
        c[NR] = $3
     }
     END {
         printf("%14s Total Amount                 %" sq ".2f\n "," ",ts) >> outfile
         for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) printf("%12s %s Record Count %11s  %s\n"," ",r[i]," ",c[i]) >> outfile
     }' FS=, OFS=, trancodestotalsumt.txt trancodestotalsumt.txt
```

The block inserted at the beginning,

```
     NR == FNR {
       width = length(sprintf("%" sq ".2f", $2));
       if(width > maxwidth) maxwidth = width;
       next
     }
```

is executed during the first pass over the file, when `FNR == NR`, the rest during the second. Note that `trancodestotalsumt.txt` is given to awk twice at the end to make this work.